# The following C++ code gives some memory allocation error

Tags: c++, memory-management, depth-first-search

I have written the  following code. It runs well on some inputs but shows an error on some others.

For example, when I try to input:

> 10000 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 4

it shows the following error just as I enter the second line of input (without even waiting for the third line)

```
a.out: malloc.c:2395: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could be the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void addEdge(list<int> *adj, int a, int b)
{
    adj[a].push_back(b);
}

int count = 1;
int dfsVisit(int i, bool *visited,list<int> *adj)
{
    visited[i] = true;
    list<int> ::iterator k;
    for(k=adj[i].begin(); k!=adj[i].end();k++)
    {
        if(!visited[*k])
        {
            count ++;
            dfsVisit(*k, visited, adj);

        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    list<int> *adj;
    long int n,i,j,a,b,m=0,k;
    long int arr[1000000];
    cin>>n>>i;
    bool *visited = new bool;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        visited[j]  = false;
    }
    adj = new list<int>[n];
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        addEdge(adj, a,b);
    }
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        if(visited[k]==false)
        {
            count = 1;
            arr[m] = dfsVisit(k, visited, adj);
            m++;
        }
    }

     /*for(k=0;k<m;k++)
    {
        cout<<arr[k];
    }*/
        long int ans = 1;
    if(m>1)
    {

        for(k=0;k<m;k++)
        {
            ans = ans * arr[k];
        }

    }
    if(m==1)
    {
        ans = 0;
    }

    cout<<ans;

}
```

Comment: visited has no memory allocated for it.

Comment: Remember that local variables, including array, are usually stored on the stack, and that the stack is limited. For example the default stack size on Windows is a single MB. On Linux the default stack size is 8 MB. Your array `arr` in the `main` function is itself almost 8MB on a system with 64-bit `long` (like a typical 64-bit Linux system). You're living on the edge!

Comment: I'm fairly certain you don't want `adj = new list<int>[n];`. You don't need `n lists`. Contrast with `new bool` where you actually ***do need*** `n bools`. Also your `new`s without `delete`s leak memory.

Comment: Try to avoid many problems alltogether: stop using `new` / `delete` and raw pointers for memory management. Don't use raw/C-style arrays. If you really need stack arrays use `std::array`, otherwise `std::vector` and use `at` instead of `operator[]` for testing/debugging/development. And don't allocate local variables on the heap. (i.e. just use `list<int> adj;` - no need for `new`). Furthermore, C++ has references for good reason: use them. [*runs well* can only mean you're not checking for leaks because you never `delete` what you `new`ed.]

Answer (score 1):

You just declared visited as a pointer, but only allocated one slot of memory for it.

```
bool *visited = new bool;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    visited[j]  = false;
}
```

Comment: How would you fix it?

Comment: @AlanStokes in this specific case, you can do bool *visited = new bool[n];

Comment: @Shiping Please correct the post so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @LogicStuff what do you mean?  I just copied the problematic part of the original code to show where the problem was. Initially I said no memory was allocated to the pointer, but immediately corrected it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is more about how you'd style your code and what features of c++ you'd use to avoid certain problems given the tools the language provides.

C++ is indeed less error-prone than C and one should make use of that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

void addEdge(std::vector<std::list<std::size_t>>& adj, 
    std::size_t a, std::size_t b)
{
    adj.at(a).push_back(b);
}

void dfsVisit(std::size_t i, std::vector<bool>& visited,
    std::vector<std::list<std::size_t>> const& adj, std::size_t& count)
{
    visited[i] = true;
    for (auto k : adj.at(i))
    {
        if (!visited.at(k))
        {
            ++count;
            dfsVisit(k, visited, adj, count);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    // initialize all variables and make the scope as small as possible
    std::size_t ni{}, ii{};
    // try to read n and i from cin
    // without the if you never know that you'll actually have valid input
    if (std::cin >> ni >> ii)
    {
        // const refs to block changes
        auto const& n = ni;
        auto const& i = ii;
        // dynamic, contiguous memory ? -> std::vector !
        // create visited vector 
        // no need to loop: we can make them all false here
        auto visited = std::vector<bool>(n, false);
        // create adj vector
        auto adj = std::vector<std::list<std::size_t>>(n);
        // you don't need arr on the stack so don't put it there
        std::vector<std::size_t> arr;
        // we know we'll have at max n entries in arr
        arr.reserve(n);
        // add edges
        for (std::size_t j = 0u; j < i; ++j)
        {
            std::size_t a{}, b{};
            if (std::cin >> a >> b)
            {
                addEdge(adj, a, b);
            }
            // TODO: else clause when input fails...
        }
        std::size_t count{};
        for (std::size_t k = 0u; k < n; ++k)
        {
            if (!visited[k])
            {
                std::size_t count = 1u;
                dfsVisit(k, visited, adj, count);
                // we know k < n and m < k since we increment at max once
                // so no at but operator[]
                arr.push_back(count);
            }
        }
        std::size_t ans = 1u;
        auto const m = arr.size();
        if (m > 1u)
        {
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k < m; ++k)
            {
                ans = ans * arr[k];
            }
        } 
        else if (m == 1)
        {
            ans = 0u;
        }

        std::cout << ans;

    }
    // TODO: else clause when input fails...

}
```